# Change button text with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, button, getelementsbytagname

I'm trying to use Javascript to change the button display text (in this case, "Push Here") using this code:

```
var button_list = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
var button = button_list[0];

<button class="btn-primary" id="btn-header-example-cs" data-toggle="modal" data-url="" data-options="" style="display: inline-block;">Push Here</button>
```

However, I can't change it with `button.value = "New Text"`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Buttons don't have values, they have content.

Comment: More precisely, the have `button.textContent = "New Text"`

Comment: you want change text on click or what??

Comment: Yup, `.textContent' was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you, guys!

Answer (score -1):

```
 var button = document.getElementsByName('button')
```

It needs to set a button name, now I'll show you

```
<button name="button" class="btn-primary" id="btn-header-example-cs" data-toggle="modal" data-url="" data-options="" style="display: inline-block;">Push Here</button>
```

I recommend you use a different name

```
 var button = document.getElementsByName('mybutton_1')
```

and html

```
<button name="mybutton_1" class="btn-primary" id="btn-header-example-cs" data-toggle="modal" data-url="" data-options="" style="display: inline-block;">Push Here</button>
```

Now you can use it

```
button.value = "New Text"
```

look not `getElementsByTagName` but `getElementsByName`